# Need Help Configuring NiFi's JsonRecordSetWriter and AvroSchemaRegistry

Tags: type-conversion, apache-nifi

I am creating a `NiFi WorkFlow` to convert `CSV` to `JSON`, and I need help configuring `ConvertRecords`'s `JsonRecordSetWriter Controller Service`.

What is happening is that a `SchemaNotFoundException` is being thrown saying

> Unable to find schema with name 'ccr' (The name I chose for the schema).

The schema is inferred from the header in the `CSV` document using `"InferAvroSchema"`, and `"UpdateAttribute"` is configured to add an attributed named `"schema.name"` that is set to `'ccr'` (per guidance from other how-tos and guidance).

The `JsonRecordSetWriter` is configured to use the Controller Service `"AvroSchemaRegistry"` with a property added to it named `"ccr"` and the value for this property is set to `"${inferred.avro.schema}"`.

I would like to have the derived schema contained in the attribute `"inferred.avro.schema"` to be used instead of having to supply the actual text of the avro schema as the value to this added property. `InferAvroSchema`'s `SchemaOutputDestination` property is set to value `"flowfile-attribute"` meaning the inferred avro schema will be put into an attribute named `"inferred.avro.schema"`.

I really need help in that I cannot specify the schema as text by virtue of the project's requirement. Rather I would like to use the schema inferred so that I can have `CSV` files of differing header and data content processed by the same workflow.

Any help and guidance you can share with me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should consider formatting your question so that it's actually readable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reader or writer with Schema Access Strategy set to "Schema Name" then it has to retrieve the schema by name from a schema registry, and the schema registry won't know anything about ${inferred.avro.schema} which is on a flow file.

You can set your writer to use Schema Access Strategy of "Schema Text" and in the schema text field put ${inferred.avro.schema} so it will dynamically get the schema text from the incoming flow file. You aren't using a schema registry at this point based on your requirements.

A different option, which may work for you... If you are on the 1.4.0 release, you could eliminate InferAvroSchema. You would use ConvertRecord with a CsvReader and set the Schema Access Strategy to "Use String Fields From Header" so the reader will infer a schema, then in your JsonRecordSetWriter set the Schema Access Startegy to "Inherit from Reader" so that it uses the same schema determined by the reader. The inherit capability doesn't exist in earlier releases which is why this is dependent on 1.4.0.

Comment: Mr Bende,  It worked!!! Thank you so very very much for clean and crisp guidance. I really appreciate it!